# Do I need to install Passenger or Unicorn in order to run my Rails app under Nginx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, nginx

I have Rails app setup on my local (OS X 10.10) and it runs perfection under Rails server. I have Nginx install but I do not know how to configure Nginx to run my local Rails app.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to install Passenger in order to run your Rials app under Nginx. [The Passenger documentation's introduction section](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/basics/ruby/fundamental_concepts.html) explains why, and how exactly Passenger helps you.

The Passenger documentation also teaches you how to deploy your app to a production server with Nginx. It covers everything, from spinning up your server to installing Ruby to installing Passenger to configuring the app.